# I have a problem while programming with using shell in makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

the code is:

```
# android/device/mediatek/build/core/build_dtboimage.mk
...
my_dtbo_id := 0                                                                   
define mk_dtboimg_cfg                                                             
$(eval name := $$(basename $1)) \
echo "file name:$(name)"; \
$(eval dts_file_name := $(notdir $(name))) \
echo "terminal_name:$$(echo $(dts_file_name) | awk -F '_' '{print $$1}')"; \
$(eval terminal_name := $$(echo $(dts_file_name) | awk -F '_' '{print $$1}')) \
$(eval main_name := $$(echo $(dts_file_name) | awk -F '_' '{print $$3}')) \
echo "terminal_name :$(terminal_name), main_name :$(main_name )"; \
...
```

and the output is:

```
file name:out/target/product/k62v1_64_pax/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/arch/arm64/boot/dts/mediatek/A3700_MT6762_V02_V01
terminal_name:A3700
terminal_name:, main_name:
```

As shown above, the code `echo "terminal_name:$$(echo $(dts_file_name) | awk -F '_' '{print $$1}')"; \` can get the right output of **A3700**, but i don't know why the output of *terminal_name* and *main_name* is **null**.

the right output i expect is **terminal_name:A3700, main_name:V02**, in other words, i hope **terminal_name** and **main_name** can correctly assigned.

What should I do to solve this problem?

thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming all the content you show is actually part of a recipe.  You need to be careful to provide full context when asking questions: it makes all the difference in the world whether the excerpt you show is part of a recipe or not part of a recipe.  But, here's a good rule of thumb:  You should *never* use the `$(eval ...)` function inside a recipe.  Similarly, you should never use the `$(shell ...)` function inside a recipe.  You should only consider violating these rules if you have a deep understanding of makefiles and GNU make, such that you'd never need to ask here :)

Answer (score 0):

You're making this far too complicated.

Remove the unnecessary functions and be generous with `$`:

```
...
dts_file_name := $$(notdir $$(name))

terminal_name := $$(shell echo $$(dts_file_name) | awk -F '_' '{print $$$$1}')
main_name := $$(shell echo $$(dts_file_name) | awk -F '_' '{print $$$$3}')

$$(info terminal: $$(terminal_name), main: $$(main_name))
...
```